# Connect OpenLDAP to Samba in read mode?

Tags: ldap, samba, openldap

We have Samba 3 based domain controller. The password backend for the domain is pdb/*nix users, this means that we do not have LDAP service running with Samba (I may be wrong on this one, but I do not see relevant ports listening on our PDC). It works for Windows logins, file shares and other primary SMB services, however now we also need to connect external service that would authenticate users against LDAP.

Is there a way to either smoothly migrate existing users and groups to OpenLDAP and use it as a storage backend, or connect OpenLDAP to Samba, so it would only read existing data from Samba and serve it over to other services?

Comment: Yes, you can store Samba user data in OpenLDAP and authenticate Samba against LDAP. Starting an installation with that backend isn't exactly easy, but possible. I am not sure about the migration of the SMB passwords into LDAP though, never tried that.

Comment: @Sven Please reread question. I know I can do clean installation of samba with openldap as a backend. But we already do have existing standalone samba server with internal storage and I don't know how to connect openldap to it so that it just reads (already existing) information from samba and not writes there. Or at least clean procedure of how to migrate data from standalone samba to samba+openldap.